# how to convert a string with html table like "<table><tr><td>12341</td></tr></table>" to JSON object?

Tags: json

How to convert a string containing HTML tags into JSON?

Any link or comment?

Comment: Converting from a HTML table seems a bit heavy. Where are you getting your data from originally? Is there no opportunity to convert raw data to JSON without going through HTML first?

Comment: You could render/instantiate the html and then stringify the table

Comment: Describe the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
  $string = "<table><tr><td>1231</td></tr></table>";
  json_encode($string);
?>
```

Comment: Vague question get vague answers

Comment: I want to do it in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running this in a browser:

```
var rows = document.getElementById('table-id').rows,
    l    = rows.length,
    i    = 0,
    array = [];

for ( ; i < l; i++ )
{
    array.push( getRowArray(rows[i]) );
}

function getRowArray ( row )
{
    var array = [],
        cells = row.childNodes,
        l     = cells.length,
        i     = 0;

    for ( ; i < l; i++ )
    {
        cells[i].nodeType == 1 && array.push( cells[i].textContent );
    }

    return array;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cqzqs/

Comment: I am getting the data from a data source as HTML string and I have to convert it into json using javascript.